# R how to get data column to rows of first and second values

Tags: r, web-scraping

Apologies, I'm a novice but I don't seem to be able to find an answer to this question.

I've scraped tabular data from a web page. After some cleaning It appears in a single unnamed column.

```
    [1] John
    [2] Smith
    [3] Tina
    [4] Jordan

    and so on.....
```

I'm obviously looking for the result of:

```
        FirstName | LastName
    [1] John        Smith
    [2] Tina        Jordan

     et al.
```

Much of what has gotten me to this point was sourced from: http://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/r-reading-webpages

A very helpful resource for beginners such as myself.

I would be grateful for any advice you can give me.

Thanks,
C R Eaton

Comment: `data.frame(FirstName=your_vec[seq(1, length(your_vec), by=2)], LastName=your_vec[seq(2, length(your_vec), by=2)], as.is=TRUE)` for example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a logical index ('i1'), create a `data.frame` by extracting the elements in the first column of the original dataset ('dat') using 'i1'.  The 'i1' elements will recycle to the length of the column, so if we do 'dat[i1,1]`, it will extract 1st element, 3rd, 5th, etc.  For the last name, we just negate the 'i1', so that it will extract 2nd, 4th, etc..

```
i1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
d1 <- data.frame(FirstName = dat[i1,1], LastName = dat[!i1, 1], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```